# Como transformar a string de uma QLineEdit em float?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4

Boa noite pessoal!
Venho tentando transformar a string de uma Qline edit em float e não consigo!! Sempre retorna o erro dizendo que não posso converter string em float. O que poso fazer para contornar isso? Estou tentando assim:

```
if float(self.qg_nodalloads[str(i)+str(0)].text())  > 0: 
   x =1
```

Comment: Qual é a string que tentou converter?

Comment: Estou tentando tanto números inteiros positivos e negativos quanto decimais. Sempre retorna "could not convert string to float"

Comment: Poderia dar exemplos?